# groovyConsole throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when starting

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I had just installed groovy in Ubuntu Studio 12.10, from the Ubuntu's Software center, and I'm trying to run the GroovyConsole, but when I execute "groovyConsole" it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:130)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getMenuShortcutKeyMask(HeadlessToolkit.java:237)
    at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit$getMenuShortcutKeyMask.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at groovy.swing.SwingBuilder.shortcut(SwingBuilder.groovy:379)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at groovy.swing.SwingBuilder.shortcut(SwingBuilder.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:793)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:776)
    at groovy.util.FactoryInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:1287)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at groovy.ui.ConsoleActions.run(ConsoleActions.groovy:27)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.build(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:1123)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.build(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:1106)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport$build.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at groovy.ui.Console.run(Console.groovy:298)
    at groovy.ui.Console$run$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at groovy.ui.Console.run(Console.groovy:264)
    at groovy.ui.Console$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at groovy.ui.Console.main(Console.groovy:199)
    ... 6 more
```

I have openJDK

> java version "1.7.0_15" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7)
>   (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.10.1) OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed
>   mode)

The groovysh and groovy command works fine.
Any advice to make it work?

Comment: I had installed Oracle's JDK 1.7.0_17 with [this instructions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7/) and now it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably had installed a "*headless*" Java, i.e. without graphic libraries.

> *[Headless mode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html)* is a system configuration in which the display device, keyboard, or mouse is lacking. Sounds unexpected, but actually you can
>   perform different operations in this mode, even with graphic data.

That's why you had the `java.awt.HeadlessException` when running the groovyConsole with it and why you solved the issue installing Oracle's JDK which is not headless (although you can run java programs in headless mode with `java -Djava.awt.headless=true`).